# Loop ONLY through a defined JSON object in a nested structure - JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following json structure (I've made it shorter for simplify):

```
{
 "employees":{"0":"Name1 Surname1", "1":"Name2 Surname2"},
 "managers":{"0":"Name3 Surname3", "1":"Name4 Surname4"},
 "teamleaders":{"0":"Name5 Surname5", "1":"Name6 Surname6"},
}
```

How can I loop ONLY through employees with JQuery? The below code gives me the whole 3 objects and I can't seem to be able to sort them according to the object name:

```
 $.each(item, function (i, item) {
    $.each(item, function (key, value) {
       //gives me ALL names and surnames            
       console.log(value);
     })
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use plain JS for this.

```
for (var employee in json.employees) {
    if (json.employees.hasownProperty(employee)) 
       console.log(json.employees[employee])   
}
```

Comment: I am marking this answer right because other answers required me to change my json structure which I couldn't do, because it wouldn't parse that way.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating the outer object, `item`, do like this.

```
var item = {
  "employees":{"0":"Name1 Surname1", "1":"Name2 Surname2"},
  "managers":{"0":"Name3 Surname3", "1":"Name4 Surname4"},
  "teamleaders":{"0":"Name5 Surname5", "1":"Name6 Surname6"},
}

$.each(item.employees, function(key, value) { ... });
```